# postgres query to order by AND partial matches and then OR matches

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have a table of `places`. Each place can have a number of `posts`. Each post can have a number of `tags`. And each `post` and `tag` are connected via a `tags_map` table. So:

```
places
  id

posts
  place_id

tags
  id
  name

tags_map
  post_id
  tag_id
```

And I'm trying to write a ranking/search query that, for e.g. if someone searched for tags `a` and `b` then they will get the results of all places that are tagged with `a` AND `b` and then places tagged with `a` OR `b`.

If a place has 2 posts associated with it, then it has the tags of all those posts. And I'm looking for partial matches - I've been trying to do with with `SIMILAR TO %(a|b)%` but that just gives me OR results.

The ranking should be as follows:

If a place has both tags, it is ranked higher than places that have either or. And if they have both tags, the ones with more total matching tags are ranked higher than the ones with less. And in the OR part of the query, they are ranked by which place has more matching tags.

I'm having trouble getting my head around the necessary JOINS that would be required and how to aggregate and prioritze the AND results followed by the OR results

Is this doable?

EDIT: Example

```
Places: a, b, c
Posts: a1, a2, b1, b2, c1
Tags: 
  * a1_wand, a1_ball
  * a1_wander
  * b1_baller
  * b2_wand
  * c1_kaballer, c1_bababall
```

If you search for `wand` and `ball` you'd first get the ones that have partially match both ball and wand, so place `a` and `b` and since `a` has more matches (2 for wand and 1 for ball) it'd be ordered before `b` (which has 1 for ball and 1 for wand). Whereas `c` matches just one of the query terms (twice, but still just one of the terms), so that comes next.

If you just search for `ball` then you'd post `c` first since it has 2 matches, and then `a` and `b` both have one match so they'd just be ordered in `created_at` date or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is just joining all the tables together, filtering for the tags you want, and aggregating to do the count:

```
select pl.*, array_agg(distinct t.name) as tags,
       count(*) as num_matches
from places pl join
     posts p
     on pl.place_id = p.place_id join
     tags_map tm
     on tm.post_id = p.post_id join
     tags t
     on t.tag_id = tm.tag_id
where t.name in ('a', 'b')
group by pl.place_id
order by count(distinct t.name) desc,
         count(*) desc;
```

EDIT:

For partial matches, it would be something like:

```
select pl.*, array_agg(distinct t.name) as tags,
       count(*) as num_matches
from places pl join
     posts p
     on pl.place_id = p.place_id join
     tags_map tm
     on tm.post_id = p.post_id join
     tags t
     on t.tag_id = tm.tag_id
where t.name ~ 'a|b'
group by pl.place_id
order by (max(t.name ~ 'a')::int) + (max(t.name ~ 'b')::int) desc,
         count(*) desc;
```

Comment: I think so yeah! The way you phrase it sounds more or less correct I think. But, can you do partial matches using the `in` operator? So if there were tags `aa`, `aaa`, `bb` then it would tread `aa` and `aaa` as a single "match" AND `bb` as matching with the `b` part?

Comment: @aliak . . . No, not using `in`.  You would use `like` or regular expressions.  However, that is not the question you asked here.

Comment: Maybe you didn't see but I did explicitly write: "And I'm looking for partial matches" in the post... It's also in the title.

Comment: @aliak . . . You do, as an afterthought, with no examples of what you mean, and what looks like incorrect matching code.  I did however add that into the answer.

Comment: Added an example. (let me know what you think seems incorrect withthe matching description, i may be able to describe it better then)

Comment: I just tried that `order by` trick! Seems to work! Would I need an special considerations with indexing here? Like anything I should maybe watch out for that may not work efficiently?

Comment: @aliak . . . You can use indexes to optimize the joins and filtering and . . . just maybe the aggregation (Postgres is smart about aggregating by a primary key).  But the final ordering is going to require a sort.